# Submitting a form in a document retrieved using a DOMParser

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, tampermonkey

I'm writing automation software in `JavaScript` within `TamperMonkey`.

My script does few `AJAX` requests which return `HTML` that I parse using a `DOMParser`. I was wondering if it was possible to submit these forms without having to actually open the newly returned `HTML` in the main page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to get your form from the document body, create a FormData object and set field values, and send a POST request.

For simplicity sake I used the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API. I also assumed that the credentials also needed to be passed from the same origin.

```
fetch('<GET URL>', {method: "GET", credentials: 'same-origin'})
  .then((response) => (response.text()))
  .then((responseBody) => {
    var html = htmlBody(responseBody);
    var form = html.querySelector('#my-form'); // whatever your form is called
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('someName', 'someValue'); // the field name will probably come from your form fields

    postForm(formData)
      .then((response) => (response.text()))
      .then((responseBody) => {
        // whatever with the form post response
    });
})

function htmlBody(string) {
  var document = new DOMParser;
  return document.parseFromString(string, 'text/html').body;
}

function postForm(formData) {
  return fetch('<POST URL>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  })
}
```